# Does the new Symmetra main fire improve damage when "connecting" or when "firing"?

Tags: overwatch

https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Symmetra#Photon_Projector

The linked page mentions the weapon powering up "when connecting", but the weapon was reworked so it doesn't connect anymore.

Its only other specialty is that it replenishes ammo while damaging barriers. It doesn't even deal more damage to barriers than to heroes.

Is that it?

For example, say I shoot at Reinhardt's barrier. Then I am dealing 180 damage per second. The barrier is destroyed. Will my damage get reset to 60 damage per second?

Comment: "It's not connecting anymore"? What do you mean by that? Any weapon can connect, it means hitting something.

Comment: It just shoot "straight". So that means if I am building up damage and then I miss, it will "decay"?

Answer (score 3):

"Connecting" does not mean "Locking on to", it means "Hitting". The weapon can't lock on to enemies anymore, but its damage will still go up after 2 seconds of hitting an enemy or a barrier, and it will still decay after 2 second of not hitting an enemy or a barrier.

Comment: can it attack multiple enemies now? I seem to have a good time with it. It's 180 dps melt barriers. Also I can hit barrier hit enemies. As long as it hits one enemies it keeps ramping up damage right?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only hit one enemy (heroes or barrier) at time. Use your secobndary fire to shoot an orb which does splash damage. I also have to mention that when you hit a barrier with primary fire, you gain ammo instead of loosing it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play with Symettra.

It seems that the new symettra is doing well.

The strategy is that when attacking barrier the amount of damage increase.

The increase is NOT because of attacking barrier.

The increase happens because well, it hits. I just need to hit something. Guys. Barriers. Anything. As long as it hits, the dps increases.

Also attacking barriers are usually easy. Barriers are large and non moving.

Once the barrier is destroyed, my symettra is doing 180 dps and I can easily connect and destroy tanks with her weapon as long as I keep hitting something within those 2 seconds.

I wonder how my damage work if I hit for 1 second and then miss and then hit another for 1 second? Will it stay at 180 dps because I don't exactly miss for 2 seconds.

The increased ammo when attacking barriers ensure that when the barriers are destroyed my symettra has **full ammo and max damage**.

That's the key.

Comment: This is what the other answer said.

Comment: My answer add things the other answer doesn't. Like telling how it's supposed to be used. Just adding ammo doesn't seem to make sense. Now it makes sense.

Comment: I upvoted your answer too. My answers add things to your.